# Representing Hydrographic survey in QGIS

Tags: qgis, data, hydrology

I have a depth Layer (soundings) and I would like to represent the labels the same way as in a Hydrographic Map.

As you can see in the image bellow, we have this kind of representation in a hydrographic map.

[image]

How can I do it in QGIS (I´m using version 3.24)?

Data Link: [Sample](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18kDUC3mI2LrVLjd1jOYprVGcHacVH-Ur?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please remove unnecessary tags. Please add example data.

Comment: So you want to display the sounding without decimal separator but rather with the decimal part as an indice ?

Comment: @J.R - Yes, I want to display the sounding values without the decimal part. The integer part is greater than the decimal. Also, the negative signal is under the interger part.